# mongo database with laravel count the query take long time

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb

I have problem and searched a lot in the internet without any result . 
I have mongo database which has data like this

```
{
"_id":ObjectId("5ddfc2da7f86bf52c2472ea5"),
"sys":"2019-11-28",
"time":ISODate("2019-11-28T12:51:38.827Z"),
"time_rcvd":ISODate("2019-11-28T12:51:38.827Z"),
"msg":"51:37 Kayseri Netcom %%01SECLOG/6/SESSION_TEARDOWN(l):IPVer=4,Protocol=icmp,SourceIP=172.16.10.252,DestinationIP=10.10.0.26,SourcePort=8,DestinationPort=0,BeginTime=1574945475,EndTime=1574945475,SendPkts=1,SendBytes=60,RcvPkts=1,RcvBytes=60,SourceVpnID=0,DestinationVpnID=0,SourceZone=tunnel,DestinationZone=trust,PolicyName=tunnel_to_trust,CloseReason=aged-out.",
"syslog_fac":23,
"syslog_sever":6,
"syslog_tag":"12:",
"procid":"12",
"pid":"-",
"level":"INFO"
}
```

what I am doing is to get data from column msg and splite it to display it in my system which I am using laravel for it . 
my problem is when user want to search about

> SourceIP = 172.16.10.252

it took a long of  time as I have more than 3 Million records in my database . 
and I am using this code to retrieve data from mongo

```
$data = Logs::where('msg', 'like', '%SourceIP=172.16.10.252')->offset(10)->limit($limit )->get();
```

but the big problem is pagination , I need to get the records count in order to make pagination , but it took long time to get the count , the system should be fast , 
this is the code which I used to get the count

```
$totalrecords = Logs::where('msg', 'like', '%SourceIP=172.16.10.252')->count();
```

so please help me if u have any suggestion to solve this problem as it is very big problem for me

Comment: You're going to have a hard time speeding this up. Left-side wildcards means that indexes cannot be used, so you really can't optimize it.

Comment: Just because you are using MongoDB doesn't mean you can get fast queries if you don't normalize your documents.

Comment: why are you storing all that data in the same column when you're using mongoDb ?

Comment: because I am using rsyslog which send data automatically and store it @N69S

Answer (score 0):

I have something but it is hardly an ideal solution.

Rather than updating your query you can update the database a bit - taking the help of aggregation pipeline. Though this will increase your database size a bit. We will add a new field which will contain only the SourceIP.

Try `db.collection.aggregate([{$addFields: { Source: { $regexFind: { input: "$msg", regex: (\w*SourceIP=\w*.[^,]+) } } } }}])`

The query will return an additional field Source.

Also, if the data lacks diversity maybe you can store these in a different collection using `$count`. Depending on your need and the frequency of the query.

You can further tweak the regex a bit to only store the IP.

The regex is here: https://rubular.com/r/IqeDtCjJBjlQrW

Comment: thank you for your reply but I have this error 2019-12-12T08:22:16.831+0200 E QUERY    [js] SyntaxError: illegal character @(shell):1:81